# Reference angular controller variables in href template

Tags: angularjs

I've received some non-angular code and am trying to figure out if it is possible to somehow reference TableController scope variables in the table-view.html template in the simplified code snippet below.

```
<div ng-controller="TableController">
    <a href="/assets/table-view.html" class="btn cbp-singlePageInline" rel="nofollow"> Show Table</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any angular expressions (`{{ }}`) here, only `ng-controller`.  *assuming* that this template is inside a larger HTML structure that has an `ng-app` which has a `TableController` defined, they should be able to be output here.  Have you tried outputting anything?  **A LOT** more context is needed to understand what your issue is here.

Comment: for the record, you aren't actually writing `table-view.html` contents out here, you have created a link that will load it as a new page.  this implies that `table-view.html` isn't really a template file, but a full HTML document.  in that situation, the contents of that page aren't going to have access to the data from this current page....   Again, it's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish with this tiny snippet.

Comment: I think my problem is exactly what @Claies mentioned---that I have a link to a separate HTML document with no direct relationship to the controller. As it is now, if I add {{ }} to table-view.html with references to scope variables in the TableController they aren't accessible.

Comment: maybe what you want instead of an `a` is `ng-include`.  This would include the contents of the `table-view.html` file inside the `div`, instead of a link to a different file. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude  Assuming `table-view.html` is indeed a template and not a full HTML app of it's own....